# Filter dinâmico ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, filter

Eu preciso inserir um filter dinâmico, que vem a partir de um select, em meu ng-repeat

```
select ng-model="campoBusca"

input type="text" ng-model="busca"

ng-repeat="funcionario in funcionarios | filter: { campoBusca: busca}"
```

mas não da certo, alguma outra alternativa?

Answer (score 1):

Você poderia especificar mais sua dúvida ? está meio vaga.

Se realmente é oque entendi, a solução abaixo deve resolver:

```
$scope.campoBusca= {campo1:'', campo2:''}


<ng-model="campoBusca[selecionado]">
<ng-repeat="funcionario in funcionarios | filter: { campoBusca: busca}" >
```

Segue um exemplo (já existente): [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lopisan/vzQKk/1/)

Comment: É isto, mas ao trocar o filtro ele deve esvaziar os outros campos, por exemplo o campo1 está selecionado e tem como valor "John", ao selecionar o campo2 ele deverá alterar o valor do campo1 para ""

Comment: Na funcao do exemplo, `$scope.changeFilterTo` você pode verificar qual é o tipo do parâmetro, e então limpar os demais campos do `$scope.search`, simples